# Como modificar la primera fila cuyo valor sea x sin tener primary keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla que tiene este formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco modificar la primera fila cuyo valor sea "$" y cambiar el "$" por " ". Hay una forma de lograrlo?
No puedo colocar ninguna primary key a la tabla.
Estoy enviando las consultas desde Python.

Estuve buscando en Google y el resultado más cercano a la solución es este: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1.
Sin embargo, debido a que todos los datos pueden repetirse, esa respuesta no sirve para mi caso.

Aquí les dejo un sql que les servirá para hacer las pruebas que necesiten: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aoxUdfjjmRmvYi61oqSDhM/0

---

No hay mucho que haya intentado, pero algo que intenté fue:

```
UPDATE tabla SET recalc=' ' WHERE (row_number() over())=3
```

Obtengo previamente la primera fila que cumple la condición con un select.

Las columnas que definen el orden serían "CODE" y "COMP", que serían de tipo "character(4)"

Tampoco me viene bien crear una nueva columna con la id, siendo que tendria qye modificar mi programa para que al eliminar filas las id no queden como 1, 2, 5, 6...

---

## Edit

No encontré la solución al problema, pero decidí cambiar la lógica de mi programa a otra, que es eliminar todos los registros que cumplen esa condición y luego reingresar los datos cambiados dentro de Python. Aun así dejo esta pregunta abierta por si a alguien le sirve la solución que digan aquí c:

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120880/discussion-on-question-by-dante-s-como-modificar-la-primera-fila-cuyo-valor-sea).

Answer (score 2):

Podrías solucionarlo así:

- Creas una consulta que devuelva el primer registro, ordenado por `code` y `comp`, donde `recalc` sea igual a `$`.

  ```
       SELECT code, comp
       FROM tabla
       WHERE recalc = '$'
       ORDER BY code ASC, comp ASC
       LIMIT 1
  ```
- Tomamos dicha consulta y la usamos en un `JOIN` para limitar las filas a actualizar.

#### Ejemplo;

```
UPDATE tabla AS A
SET recalc = ' '
FROM (
   SELECT code, comp
   FROM tabla
   WHERE recalc = '$'
   ORDER BY code ASC, comp ASC
   LIMIT 1
) AS B
   WHERE A.code = B.code
   AND A.comp = B.comp;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dYTNu5BoHHA9qPjWrnaDpD/0)</kbd>

---

Nota:

- Para mejorar el rendimiento de esta consulta, sería ideal crear **un indice doble** de las columnas `code` y `comp`

Referencias:

- [PostgreSQL UPDATE Join](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/)

Comment: Me temo que tu solución tiene un problema. No puedo hacer que code y comp sean primary keys porque los datos se repiten. Y sospecho que tu solución no cubre ese caso.

Comment: Tu solución no me funciona, tira error en la palabra "inner" de "inner join"

Comment: @DanteS. he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la actualización! Yo hice una a la pregunta!

Comment: @DanteS. No entiendo: actualizaste y dices que cambiaste pero que dejas la pregunta. Tú eres el dueño de tu pregunta, así que eres quien decide si es útil o no, resuelve la pregunta o no :)

Comment: @Alfabravo no responde la pregunta. Por mi, ya esta pregunta estaria borrada, pero quiero ver si alguien responde algo util y eso le sirve a alguien más. O es mejor borrar directamente la pregunta?

Comment: O sea, probaste la respuesta actualizada y no funciona? Por qué no funciona? Algo que guíe al que intenta responder; tu actualización sólo dice que lo hiciste diferente y ya :/

Comment: Lo dice en los comentarios de la respuesta actualizada. Pero te lo digo aqui. La respuesta no sirve debido a que puede haber dos filas iguales en la tabla. Y esa respuesta modificaria ambas filas.

Comment: @Alfabravo me olvide de notificarte, perdon

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET RECALC = "" WHERE  CODE = CODE AND RECALC = "$";
```

Esta sentencia lo que hace es actualizar el campo `RECALC` donde se cumpla la condición que necesitas. Lo único que debes de hacer es enviarle como parámetro el `CODE`.

Comment: Esa consulta actualizaría todas las filas donde recalc='$' y busco actualizar solo el primera fila donde la condición se cumpla. Sin embargo, gracias igual por la respuesta!

Comment: Tienes razón, agrega a la clausula WHERE la condición del id = id AND RECALC = "$".

Comment: He modificado la respuesta. Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: He considerado esa alternativa. Pero al modificar la tabla y agregar una columna "id", tendria que modificar todo mi programa para que reacomode las ids cada vez que se borran filas. Perdon por no avisarlo antes. Gracias igual por la edición! c:

Comment: Es decir que las ids no qieden como 1, 2, 6, 7...

Comment: Ya agregue ese detalle a la pregunta!

Comment: Entiendo. Volví a editar.

Comment: Perdon por no dejarlo claro en la pregunta, pero las filas pueden repetirse. Por lo que esa consulta actualizaría todas las filas con dicho code. Es una historia similar al del id. Pero está mejor! Gracias igual nuevamente!

Comment: Agregué datos nuevos a la pregunta, eres bienvenido a leerla nuevamente por si algo de lo nuevo te sirve c: